# Max Values from Text File that has multiple columns

Tags: python, io, max

After doing some calculations i have **a text file** in the format:

```
word1 word2 0.1111 hyp1 hyp2 0.1111111111111111
word3 word4 0.2 hyp3 hyp4 0.07692307692307693
word5 word6 0.2 hyp5 hyp6 0.3333333333333333
```

So this has 6 columns, two words which have a value and then next to that 2 hypernyms which have a value.

My goal is to get the top 10 highest value pairs and write to a file (Not the part im struggling on)

My question is what approach should I be taking so that it looks at column 3 and 6 and then puts in the file column 1,2,3 or 4,5,6 in a file..so i might get a text file looking like:

```
chapter tom 0.08333333333333333 section black 0.1
answer tom 0.09090909090909091 statement black 0.1111111111111111
boy wonder 0.08333333333333333 man astonishment 0.09090909090909091
tom answer 0.09090909090909091 turkey statement 0.058823529411764705
old lady 0.08333333333333333 past woman 0.1
pulled spectacle 0.1111111111111111 tear sight 0.1111111111111111
```

Comment: There are a few different ways you might do this, I'm interested to see which approach you've taken and what issues you're finding. People can then help you refine what you have into something that works. At present, it looks like you're trying to find someone to do this for you.

Comment: Well not quite asking someone to do it for me but maybe a few ideas on the different approaches I could take. Because If it was just the 3 columns I think I could do it, but since there are 6 columns which consist of different pairs im unsure on how to break it down

Comment: If you know that every line is in that structure, you could read in, and split on whitespace, then make a list where each item is a tuple of string, string, integer. You could import using numpy and do it that way switching type when doing the numerical comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my solution

```
import re

def my_sort(val):
    pattern = r'[0-9]+\.[0-9]+'
    p = re.findall(pattern, val)
    return float(p[0])

with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    txt = f.read()

pattern1 = r'[a-z]+[0-9]* [a-z]+[0-9]* [0-9]+\.[0-9]+'
p1 = re.findall(pattern1,txt)
p1.sort(key=my_sort)
result = p1[::-1]

with open('text2.txt','w') as f:
    for i in result:
        f.write(i+'\n')
```

the output in the file text2.txt is

```
hyp5 hyp6 0.3333333333333333
word5 word6 0.2
word3 word4 0.2
hyp1 hyp2 0.1111111111111111
word1 word2 0.1111
hyp3 hyp4 0.07692307692307693
```

with the other example:

```
tear sight 0.1111111111111111
pulled spectacle 0.1111111111111111
statement black 0.1111111111111111
past woman 0.1
section black 0.1
tom answer 0.09090909090909091
man astonishment 0.09090909090909091
answer tom 0.09090909090909091
old lady 0.08333333333333333
boy wonder 0.08333333333333333
chapter tom 0.08333333333333333
turkey statement 0.058823529411764705
```

Comment: With this code, why does it work with the example data i provided but if its a much larger file, the list is empty? The format of the full list is the same but does contain some 0's but still shouldn't affect it? Edit; i might know the reason. My top row is just text headers i'lll skip that line and retry

Comment: Nope, I removed the first row of just pure text and still returns an empty list

Comment: Oh i see..because your regex is trying to find a wordX where x is a number, but that was just an example because technically my file just has word + value

Comment: I updated the code. Maybe there is something in the rest of the data that can throw it off. I can only go by the sample data.

Comment: Sorry I updated the main thread with the first few lines of what the actual file looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Load the file into a Pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('input.txt', sep=' ', header=None)
```

Split the dataframe into two dataframes, `df_left` (first three columns) and `df_right` (last three columns):

```
df_left = df.iloc[:, :3]
df_right = df.iloc[:, 3:]
```

Append `df_right` below `df_left`. Note that we need to rename the columns of one of the dataframes for the append to work correctly:

```
df_right.columns = [0, 1, 2]
df = df_left.append(df_right)
```

Sort the data frame by the values in the last column (i.e. columns no. 2), in the descending order:

```
df = df.sort_values(2, ascending=False)
```

Finally, save the dataframe to a file:

```
pd.to_csv('output.txt', sep=' ', header=None, index=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
import re


data = [
    "word1 word2 0.1111 hyp1 hyp2 0.1111111111111111",
    "word3 word4 0.2 hyp3 hyp4 0.07692307692307693",
    "word5 word6 0.2 hyp5 hyp6 0.3333333333333333"]

pattern = r"^(\S+\s\S+\s\d+.\d+)\s(\S+\s\S+\s\d+.\d+)$"
pairs = []
for line in data:
    match = re.match(pattern, line)
    pairs.append(match.group(1).split())
    pairs.append(match.group(2).split())

for pair in pairs:
    print(pair)

print("======")

pairs.sort( key=lambda value: float(value[2]))

for pair in pairs:
    print(pair)
```

Output:

```
['word1', 'word2', '0.1111']
['hyp1', 'hyp2', '0.1111111111111111']
['word3', 'word4', '0.2']
['hyp3', 'hyp4', '0.07692307692307693']
['word5', 'word6', '0.2']
['hyp5', 'hyp6', '0.3333333333333333']
======
['hyp3', 'hyp4', '0.07692307692307693']
['word1', 'word2', '0.1111']
['hyp1', 'hyp2', '0.1111111111111111']
['word3', 'word4', '0.2']
['word5', 'word6', '0.2']
['hyp5', 'hyp6', '0.3333333333333333']
```

After sort, you can write this data to file:

```
with open('new_file_name', 'w') as new_file:
    for pair in pairs:
        new_file.write(' '.join(pair))
```